# UIImagePickerController & view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, uivewcontroller

I have a simple Swift project in which:

**ViewController A** (`class ViewController: UIViewController`) presents **ViewController B** -- (`class WebViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler`).

ViewController B is essentially just a WKWebView, here's its `viewDidLoad()`:

```
let contentController = WKUserContentController();
contentController.addScriptMessageHandler(
    self,
    name: "eventHandler"
)

let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.userContentController = contentController

webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero, configuration: config)
webView.navigationDelegate = self
webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = false
view = webView
```

**So, when ViewController B is presented, I basically just have a web browser on the entire screen.**

The problem I'm running into is that, if the User (while on a webpage) clicks a "File Upload / File Picker", first I see this:

> Passed in type public.item doesn't conform to either public.content or
>   public.data. If you are exporting a new type, please ensure that it
>   conforms to an appropriate parent type.  the behavior of the
>   UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because the item width must
>   be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section
>   insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right
>   values.
>
> The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is
>   <_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x12e30f270>, and it is
>   attached to ;
>   animations = { bounds.origin=;
>   bounds.size=;
>   position=; }; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}> collection
>   view layout: <_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout:
>   0x12e30f270>.

Then, if the User chooses "Take Photo or Video" or "Photo Library" from the iOS options list, I get this:

> Warning: Attempt to present UIImagePickerController: 0x12d192200 on
>   My.WebViewController: 0x12e2883e0 whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!

The result is that:

1. The photo library picker // camera app never appears.
2. ViewController B undergoes an animated dismiss, for some reason.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I tried to provide the relevant code, but I can paste more if needed.  Thank you.

**-- UPDATE --------**

Okay, so after more research, there are actually two separate things going on:

1. The first error is a function of how the "file picker" is handled by a mobile browser.  [See here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/solved-anyone-got-filepicker-working-with-cordova/11689) ... grand scheme of things, not a big deal.
2. The second error `Attempt to present UIImagePickerController...` -- the more debilitating of the two -- is uglier.

If a ViewController with a WKWebView is presented from ***another*** ViewController then, upon the User trying to "pick" an image (from library or camera), iOS will attempt to present the UIImagePicker ***from*** your WKWebView ViewController, which is what you want.

Unfortunately, for a reason I don't yet know, the act of the User trying to "pick" an image also causes iOS to dismiss the presented view controller ... which, in this case, is your WKWebView controller :(  As such, the WKWebView ViewController dismisses, so it then isn't in the window hierarchy when it attempts to present the UIImagePicker -- hence, the error.

My solution (which is pretty hacky, but works for my particular use case), is as follows; I hope this helps someone:

1. Instantiate the WKWebView ViewController (**ViewController B**)
2. Set **VC B** as the app's root view controller
3. Present **VC B** from **ViewController A**
4. Dismiss **VC A**

This essentially makes it so the WKWebView cannot be dismissed, sidestepping the problem.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Browser") as! WebViewController
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc

self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: { () -> Void in
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
})
```

Comment: I have the same situation right now. As for first issue: it only appears on simulator, but not on actual device. The second issue is resolved by answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37380333

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing int in `viewDidLoad(){}` function currently then try to move code into override `viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {}` I had the same problem today and it fixed it.

Comment: I have the same problem, but this solution not fixed it for me.