# WebView dismissed if choose file and select photo Library

Tags: swift3, webview, uiwebview

I'm working on a project where I'm using webView and on site in webView have form where i can add file,

[image]

after need select what use, i select Photo library,

[image]

after controller will dismissed.

In Controller i use

```
  webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: ln)!))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modal view closes when selecting an image in WkWebView iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37380333/modal-view-closes-when-selecting-an-image-in-wkwebview-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set Delegate to webview.

   webView.delegate = self
2. Then after call delegate method of webview.

   func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)

   **Enter your code above method of choose file and select photo Library.**

Comment: What method you mean need in webViewDidFinishLoad?

Comment: Yes, i use this method.  func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        
        print("Finish Loading")

    }